# Picasso cache returning transformed image instead of original

Tags: android, picasso, image-caching

I am using Picasso for my Android app. Using Picasso transforms i rendered the images transformed in some sections of my app, but when i try to render the image in another part, I get the transformed image as well. How can i get the original image to display it without transformation?

Here is a code example.

```
String imageUrl = "http://path/image.png";

CustomTransformation *trans= new CustomTransformation();
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).transform(trans).into(myImageView1);
Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(myImageView2);
```

After this the two image views are displaying the image with the transformation applied to both of them

Comment: Please provide some code!

Comment: @PatrickMA i added some code, now it is more clear

Answer (score 3):

Probably you don't set the transformation key so the caching mechanism doesn't see the difference.
Example:

```
private Transformation blur = new Transformation() {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        Bitmap blurred = BitmapUtils.createBlurredBitmap(source);
        source.recycle();
        return blurred;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "blurred";   //this will be added to the key that Picasso uses for caching
    }
};
//key: <uri>\nblurred
void loadAndBlur(Uri uri, ImageView mPhoto) {
        picasso.load(uri).transform(blur).into(mPhoto);
}
//key: <uri>
void load(Uri uri, ImageView mPhoto) {
        picasso.load(uri).into(mPhoto);
}
```